# Working example of udisks2 (udisksctl) mount with tmpfs

Tags: tmpfs, udisks

A Google search for '+udisksctl +tmpfs' returned no hits.

I've tried many, many variants on this but all of them fail.

Here's my current best guess:

```
udisksctl mount -t tmpfs --options size=100 -b /tmp/d20170216-15899-17yq59a
```

Which returns this error:

```
Error looking up object for device /tmp/d20170216-15899-17yq59a
```

If I remove the '-b', I get a usage error:

```
Usage:
  udisksctl mount [OPTION...]
```

If it matters, I'm on CentOS 7.

Comment: 1. `-b` is supposed to be used with e.g. `/dev/sdc3` i.e. it is the short option for `--block-device` 2. Even if you used a block device instead of that path you may still get an error like `Error mounting /dev/sdc3: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.OptionNotPermitted: Requested filesystem type 'tmpfs' is neither well-known nor in /proc/filesystems nor in /etc/filesystems`

Comment: @don_crissti ... which could be fixed by editing the PolicyKit rules and allowing those actions, though.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is not possible. It seems that udisks2 won't work since it's designed for media files.